# If an Animagus eats something that is harmful to the Animagus' form would it harm them?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

If an Animagus eats something that is harmful to the Animagus' form would it harm them?

For example, if Sirius Black was in his Animagus form as a dog, would he get sick if he ate chocolate? If he ate enough could he die? Would Sirius be affected by the chocolate in Animagus form?

Comment: I've edited this so it reads as more of a general case question rather than something very specific so it will hopefully get better answers. Feel free to roll back my edits if you want to however.

Comment: Or vice versa - if one's Animagus form is a pig (who can eat trash literally) does that mean the person can also eat trash without consequences?

Comment: Hmmmm.... Tape worms are tape worms, so, yes?

Comment: @ShanaTar Pettigrew was able to survive as a rat for several years, presumably living off of pet food.

Comment: To close voters: this has an answer within canon and is not opinion based.

Comment: @Skooba I don't see how your quote actually answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

**A witch or wizard in Animagus form will eat the food of their animal form:**

> An Animagus is a witch or wizard who can transform at will into an animal. While in their animal form, they retain most of their ability to think as a human, their own sense of identity and their memories. They will also retain normal human life expectancy, even if they take their animal form for long periods of time. However, feelings and emotions are simplified and they will have many animal desires, **feeding off whatever their animal body craves, rather than demanding human food.**

The above quote comes from the e-book: *Short Stories from Hogwarts of Heroism, Hardship, and Dangerous Hobbies*, Chapter One: Animagi.

One would then assume that if they ate something toxic to their animal form it would indeed be harmful to them.

However, since most Animagi are not in their animal forms for *that* long, I would expect they would merely transform back into their human form prior to eating.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly never addressed in canon.

Personally I would lean towards no but the only answer would be maybe

Is a human magically transformed into a dog really a dog for the sake of chocolate being poisonous to them, what happens to stomach contents when someone transforms.  Without knowing precisely how the magic works I do not think anyone could say for certain.

Comment: In most fiction it is usual that a human transformed into an animal also eats like this animal. Often for comedy effect transformed back to human form while doing so, ending up as a human with a rat into his mouth or something like that. So I would think that the trope tends more to yes. In animal form the eating habits of the animal take over. What happended to stomach content is another question. Also don't forget that the content of the much larger human stomach do not fit into the dogs or cats stomach. So some magic must be in effect here also.

Answer (score -2):

i dont think they would die because to maintain the animagous form takes effort.  So if sirius were to eat a bunch of chocolate he might become sick but then would revert to his human form before dying and then be perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? If you could back up the claim that it takes effort to remain in the form, I.e. with a quote, this could be quite a good answer. You can [edit] it to do so.